# How to run two functions simultaneously without pausing each other in asp net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using an `SMS web service panel`. In `controller action HttpPost` I call a method for sending SMS. I want to run this function simultaneously but I don't want to use `async thread`. Because first method is **paused**. Sending SMS is not important and if it failed to connect SMS web service I don't want to paused main action. How can I run these two methods simultaneously?

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult ServicesRes(FormCollection collection)
{

    .
    .
    .

    sendSMS();

    ....

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


}
```

[UPDATE]

I tried async but not work

Main Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult ServicesRes(FormCollection collection)
{

    .
    .
    .

    await sendSMS();

    ....

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


}
```

//Send SMS

```
private async Task sendSMS()
{
      ...
      await Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Comment: you can use Task.Run to execute your sendSMS() method, which will create separate thread and your main thread execution remains as it is. Well, this is not asyn thread, it is pure separate thread creation which is the only solution of your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use kind of Asynchronous programming here, for example this code run a thread without blocking current execution.

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task task = new Task(()=>
            {
                sendSMS();
            });
            task.Start();
```

In c# you can also make your sendSMS async. for example like this

```
 public async Task sendSMS()
        {
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, your first solution solved my problem, but when I use async, as you and @DSA said, It's not work (Works like sync function call)

Comment: @MehdiRahimi please show the code you write for async. I will check.

Comment: as long as you don't put await keyword before sendSMS() it should not block the current thread

Comment: I put await, but the result did not changed.